# how to create multi company group on facebook workplace using graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-workplace

I have created an app in facebook workplace. Using app access token i want to create multi company group . As per documentaion to create group we should use

```
POST graph.facebook.com
  /{community-id}/groups?
    name={...}&
    description={...}&
    privacy=OPEN
```

So how we can create a multi company group ?

Answer (score 0):

you can't create MCG through APIs.
The APIs are not available in the MCG, except few use cases like read the post on behalf of a member of the group.